# How to use NativeBase DatePicker

Tags: react-native, datepicker, native-base

Given this [DatePicker Api](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/blob/v2.5.1/src/basic/DatePicker.js) from NativeBase v2.5.1 how am I supposed to capture the change date event with the new selected date?

If I understand well the selected date is only available in the internal state of the component:

```
setDate(date) {
    this.setState({ chosenDate: new Date(date) });
}
```

I imagine I can use the react native ref api but it doesn't seem right since other similar components do offer the onDateChange event, eg: [react-native-datepicker](https://github.com/xgfe/react-native-datepicker)

Comment: See PR https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/pull/1987

Comment: Yes, that seems better! Why not doing it for Android as well?

Comment: Fixed with [v2.5.2](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/releases/tag/v2.5.2)

Comment: ```<DatePicker
  style={{ width: 200 }}
  date={this.state.date}
  mode="date"
  placeholder="select date"
  format="YYYY-MM-DD"
  minDate="2016-05-01"
  maxDate="2017-11-01"
  confirmBtnText="Confirm"
  cancelBtnText="Cancel"
  onDateChange={date => this.dateChangedHandler(date)}
/>```

Comment: The above should solve your requirement. just add the function dateChangedHandler()

Comment: see this https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#date-picker-def-headref

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check docs for Date Picker https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#date-picker-def-headref

Sample example from NativeBase KitchenSink https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase-KitchenSink/blob/master/src/screens/datepicker/index.js

Fixed with [v2.5.2](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/releases/tag/v2.5.2)

Comment: @Supriya Kalghatgi , While i am using Date Picker from Native base, when date picker shows up on ios, is shows with a white background instead of the UI in which date picker is called. native-base version : "2.7.2" , is there any solution or is it a bug? ,please check

Answer (score 2):

Fixed in native-base v2.6.1 onwards.

```
<DatePicker
formatChosenDate={date => {return moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');}}
..... />
```

Comment: I'm trying to manipulate the default date in code by e.g. adding 6 months to today's date, the value is updated in the state, but doesn't get updated within the component (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62147922/react-native-native-base-datepicker-issue). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can set,

```
onDateChange={(date) => this.setDate(date)}
```

and make sure you have updated the native-base version to to v2.6.1

Check out : [v2.6.1](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/releases/tag/v2.6.1)

Answer (score 0):

```
import {DatePicker} from 'native-base'

        this.state = {
            date : ''
        }
    render(){
        console.log('selected date',this.state.date)
        render(
            <View>
                <DatePicker
                    defaultDate={new Date(1994, 3, 23)}
                    // minimumDate={new Date()}
                    textStyle={'#000'}
                    placeHolderTextStyle={'#000'}
                    onDateChange={(date) => this.setState({ date })}
                 />
            </View>
        )
    }
```