# React-native native-base datepicker issue

Tags: react-native, native-base

I'm wondering if you could help me fix the following issue. Using the native-base datepicker I am trying to manipulate the default date. On load from the parent component I am setting it to today's date. Then using some logic to add x number of months. The date is then updated in the state, but it's not being mapped to the datepicker. See code below:

```
// Parent state from parent component

state = {
  index: 0,
  routes: [
    { key: '1', title: 'STEP 1' },
    { key: '2', title: 'STEP 2' },
    { key: '3', title: 'STEP 3' },
    { key: '4', title: 'STEP 4' }
  ],
  purposes: [],
  purpose_Of_Examination_Id: 0,
  colours: [],
  colour_Id: 0,
  first_Examination: false,
  installed_Correctly: null,
  defect_Reason_Id: 0,
  defect_Reasons: [],
  hasDefects: false,
  defect: '',
  inspected_At: moment().toDate(),
  next_Inspection_Date: moment().toDate()
}

// Child component

constructor(props: any) {
  super(props);

  this.state = this.props.parentState;
}

async componentDidMount() {
  this.bindDates();
}

bindDates() {
  var inspected_At = moment().toDate();
  var next_Inspection_Date = moment().toDate();  
  var safe_For_Use = false;

  if (this.props.inspection.hasDefects == true) {
    next_Inspection_Date = moment().toDate();
    safe_For_Use = false;
  } else {
    next_Inspection_Date = moment(inspected_At).add(this.props.equip.inspection_Interval, 'M').toDate();
    safe_For_Use = true;
  }

  this.setState({inspected_At: inspected_At, next_Inspection_Date: next_Inspection_Date, safe_For_Use: safe_For_Use}, () => {
    console.log("NEXT INSPECTION DATE state: " + this.state.next_Inspection_Date);
  });
}

// Part of view

<View style={styles.nextInspectionDateContainer}>
  <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
    <Text style={styles.inputLabel}>Next Inspection Date:</Text>
    <DatePicker
    locale="en_GB"
    defaultDate={this.state.next_Inspection_Date}
    formatChosenDate={date => { return moment(date).format('DD/MM/YYYY'); }}
    onDateChange={(date) => { this.setState({ next_Inspection_Date: date }) }}
    />
  </View>
</View>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty common (:

`this.setState()` is `async` so you will need to return a promise from `this.setState()` to a function which will update your `DatePicker` instead of just logging them. Then you can call `forceupdate()` to show your updates.

if you were using stateless functional components, it will be much better as you would only need a simple `Hook` to get all the above done.

keep in mind from docs:

> Normally you should try to avoid all uses of forceUpdate() and only
>   read from this.props and this.state in render().

Comment: I just log the data to ensure it's correct. However, I expect the component to update as it's tied to the state. Am I missing something?

Comment: I ended up going with react-native-modal-datetime-picker (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-modal-datetime-picker) as I found it a lot easier to manipulate dates programmatically.

Comment: @jmckie, the main idea is that your log is happening before your state updates, thats why i suggested using a promise to update the `DatePicker` or just logging them